# Server not responding after updating honeybadger

Tags: ruby, api, sinatra, ruby-grape

As recommended, I updated [honeybadger gem](http://docs.honeybadger.io/article/197-upgrading-to-honeybadger-2-0) to version 2.0.
I follow all the instructions while upgrading as mention [here](http://docs.honeybadger.io/article/197-upgrading-to-honeybadger-2-0).

Next when I started my server after upgrading i.e `shotgun -p3000`, and load page, request gets timeout and throw:

> ERROR: Got response code: 500

And Log look like this:

> I, [2015-06-02T10:43:01.447813 #11587]  INFO -- : Starting Honeybadger version 2.0.12 level=1 pid=11587
>
> I, [2015-06-02T10:43:01.448585 #11586]  INFO -- : Starting Honeybadger version 2.0.12 level=1 pid=11586
>
> W, [2015-06-02T10:43:01.454212 #11587]  WARN -- : Initializing development backend: data will not be reported. level=2 pid=11587
>
> W, [2015-06-02T10:43:01.454692 #11586]  WARN -- : Initializing development backend: data will not be reported. level=2 pid=11586
>
> I, [2015-06-02T10:43:01.462911 #11588]  INFO -- : Starting Honeybadger version 2.0.12 level=1 pid=11588
>
> W, [2015-06-02T10:43:01.472935 #11588]  WARN -- : Initializing development backend: data will not be reported. level=2 pid=11588
>
> I, [2015-06-02T10:43:04.496411 #11601]  INFO -- : Starting Honeybadger version 2.0.12 level=1 pid=11601
>
> W, [2015-06-02T10:43:04.500226 #11601]  WARN -- : Initializing development backend: data will not be reported. level=2 pid=11601
>
> I, [2015-06-02T10:43:07.004766 #11614]  INFO -- : Starting Honeybadger version 2.0.12 level=1 pid=11614
>
> W, [2015-06-02T10:43:07.008677 #11614]  WARN -- : Initializing development backend: data will not be reported. level=2 pid=1161

I am using following tools:

1. Ruby 2.1.2
2. Sinatra 1.4.6
3. Grape 0.11.0
4. HoneyBadger 2.0.12

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In previous honeybadger version i.e ~> 1.9, we had to specify `Honeybadger::Rack::ErrorNotifier` in config.ru file. But after upgrading, we have to remove `Honeybadger::Rack::ErrorNotifier` from config.ru file(upgrading document does not consist this info).

After removing `Honeybadger::Rack::ErrorNotifier` from config.ru,  it works as expected.

Next, If you find your server slow and spawns more pids after upgrading then update your honeybadger gem

`gem 'honeybadger', '2.1.0.beta.1'`.